# Universal Linking Validator (Branch) issue

Tags: ios, terminal, branch, ios-universal-links

So I am trying to use the Universal Linking Validator on Branch's website. I downloaded the script and opened the terminal and entered:

```
$ bash ulv_script.sh
```

Then I dragged and drop the project’s `.xcodeproj` file into the terminal window the result was:

> ulv_script.sh: No such file or directory

How am I suppose to get the link I need?

Here are the directions I am following:

https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-linking-validator/guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonas from Branch here.

The error you are seeing is because your terminal is in a different directory then the script. You can get around this by using the `cd` command to navigate to the location of the script.

Alternatively, you can enter `bash` into the terminal, drag and drop the downloaded script into the terminal window, and then drag and drop your .xcodeproj file into the window. Using this method, you should end up with a command that looks like `bash /Users/jbauer/Downloads/ulv_script.sh /Users/jbauer/Desktop/BranchStuff/Branch-TestBed-Swift/TestBed-Swift.xcodeproj` Note the space between the path to the script, and the path to the Xcode project.

Feel free to ping me if you run into any other issues, and I'd be happy to lend a hand.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! The results only show 1 error: Not able to locate projects url scheme. I have my apps url scheme in info.plist under Url types, URL Schemes. How do I fix this error?

Comment: @Elizabeth429 This is just a warning letting you know that there was a setting we weren't able to check. Although this tool is called the Universal Linking Validator, it actually checks several other settings, to help you get set up in one fell swoop. URI schemes are one of the settings that don't directly affect Universal Links. So long as your Universal Links are working now, you can ignore this message.